# get region of interest using binary mask c++ itk

Tags: c++, mask, itk

I am pretty new to ITK and have therefore almost no experiences using it.
My problem is:

I have two nifti images: one medical image and one binary image representing a Volume of interest. 
I would like to extract from the medical image only the region of the volume of interest. I would like to store the intensity value of this region in a multidimensional array.
Until now I read the image and the mask and stored their values in a multidimensional array. i could now compare the values pixel by pixel but I hope, there might be an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a job for [Region of interest filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1RegionOfInterestImageFilter.html). First you need to determine the "bounding region" around your mask. You should use an [iterator](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Iterators/ImageRegionIterator) for that. If you construct your pipeline (reader->regionOfInterest->writer) without intermediate `Update()` calls and with [streaming](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Core/Common/StreamAPipeline/Documentation.html), with some image formats (e.g. meta-image) your intensity image does not need to be even completely read from disk.

You might also be interested in [LabelGeometryImageFilter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1LabelGeometryImageFilter.html).